# IIS7 Require SSL with must Require option

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-web-api, client-certificates, ca

I hosted an ASP.NET Web API project in my Windows 7(IIS7) developer machine on HTTPS(443) and SSL Required ticked with Require Option true.

For testing I give its host header value : www.certtest.com, and the same I add in host file of local machine.

Also we have a W2k3 machine where we've configured the CA and obtain test certificates from it.

We import same certificate in IIS7.0 for client authentication.

When we try access site, the first time it asks me for certificate and after that certificate get installed with root certificate in my local store but i see 403.7 Forbidden error immediately.

Also, I tried with self signed certificate. 
Same problem with that too.

Do we require a valid trial certificate for client authentication by Thwate type CA to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a case where we don't have valid certificates, for testing you can set SSL Settings as Accept and see if things work fine for you.

However you will need valid certificates for the same.